# Strange behaviour of filters in disconnected tables of star schema

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have sales, client and location tables.

Sales is fact table having client_id and location_id connections (*:1) to the dim tables.

Client table has client_id, client_name, location_id

Location table has location_id, location_name

There is no relationship made between client and location table.

I have made a table visualization. The values section has clientname (from client table) and locationname (from location table). I have also added a slicer for locationname (from location table).

Selecting a location on the slicer results in the table showing clients from that selected location. I'm confused how this works as there is no relation between location table and client table. Any ideas?

Comment: Do sales and client table related?

Comment: Sales is fact table having client_id and location_id connections (*:1) to client and location tables. One direction only